# Using mongodump: "mongodump: command not found"

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm trying to get a dump of my local database and it seems I should be using:

```
mongodump --host localhost:3002
```

However, the terminal then tells me:

```
-bash: mongodump: command not found
```

Am I missing something? Or going about this the wrong way? I'm using it on Mac from the terminal.

I installed mongo (I think) using the following commands:

```
curl http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.5.tgz > mongodb.tgz

tar -zxvf mongodb.tgz
```

Comment: How did you install MongoDB?

Comment: @Sammaye `curl http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.5.tgz > mongodb.tgz` then `tar -zxvf mongodb.tgz`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`brew tap mongodb/brew; brew install mongodb-community`
will also install `mongodump`.

If you don't have the `brew` command, you really should consider install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: Can the downvote comment on what is not relevant about this? It is accurate according to the question and is actually tested and working out of the box. Plus it is a best practice and updatable.

Comment: For os x and macports use `sudo port install mongo-tools`

Comment: Getting Error: No available formula with the name "mongo" when using this.

Comment: I've added a note at the top of the answer that this answer is out of date and that the `mongo` homebrew formula no longer exists. The following commands don't work either to install mongodump: `brew tap mongodb/brew; brew install mongodb-community`.

So I don't know how you install mongodump via homebrew or another method on OS X.

Comment: I got Error: mongodb-community: Failed to download resource "libnghttp2_bottle_manifest" Installing mongodb-database-tools as suggested in the answer below stackoverflow.com/a/63475905/1892584 worked however.

Answer (score 81):

As of [MongoDB 4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4) (released July 30, 2020), you may need to install `mongodump` separately because the MongoDB Database Tools (which comprises `mongodump`, `mongorestore`, and more) [has become its own project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4/#migration-to-mongodb-database-tools-project).

I found this out because I upgraded to MongoDB 4.4 today and `mongodump` stopped working.

```
$ mongodump
zsh: command not found: mongodump
```

I'm on macOS and installed MongoDB via Homebrew. To get `mongodump` and friends back, I installed the MongoDB Database Tools via Homebrew:

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

If you're on a different OS, this should help:

[MongoDB Database Tools Installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/)

Comment: Ran into the very same issue after upgrading to 4.4. Thanks for taking the time to update  this question with a current answer.

Comment: This is definitely the answer in 2020 and beyond. Thanks!

Comment: @AttRigh installing mongodb-database-tools is suggested in this answer

Comment: Ah, wrong answer..

Comment: Doesn't work for Mac M1/M2.

Comment: @ShubhamA. just tested on my m1 and it works

Answer (score 12):

If you just extracted the .tgz file, the mongodump command is not available in your **PATH**. Go to your /bin/ subdirectory inside the directory where you have extracted mongodb.tgz, the mongodump binary should be there. Now you can execute:

```
./mongodump --host localhost:3002
```

It's much better though to install MongoDB with a package manager. Read this page:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
and use, for example, **Homebrew** to install MongoDB and have all the necessary binaries in PATH.

Comment: Ah I was in the correct directory, it's just I didn't put the ./ before. Thanks for the info about the package manager though :)

Answer (score 12):

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

Comment: This gave me the message "mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools 100.1.1 is already installed, it's just not linked. You can use `brew link mongodb-database-tools` to link this version.", which led to the solution.

Answer (score 8):

For using mongodump, `mongo-tools` library has to be installed from os package manager.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably just not in your path, it should be in the same directory as your "mongod", and you can then run it with:

```
/path/to/bin/mongodump --host localhost:3002
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to install mongo-tools to have mongodump.

```
sudo apt-get install mongo-tools
```

Comment: The question is about macOS operation system. Your answer is valid for Linux distribution based on Debian.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the official MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) now. For example, to install the 3.2 version:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@3.2
```

Then follow the steps to update your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

#### For Windows Users

You can download the **MongoDB Database Tools** from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools)

And you can read the installation guide [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have mongodb already installed then just installing `mongodb-database-tools` and linking it solves the issue -

```
# install and link
brew install mongodb-database-tools
brew link mongodb-database-tools
```