# MongoDump Command Not Found on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, mlab

Inside `AWS EC2` Instance, I am trying to import my `MongoLab` hosted Database using `mongodump` command.

`sudo mongodump -h dsXXXX.mongolab.com:xxxxx -d testDB -u XXXXX -p YYYYYYY -o dumpmongolabs`

I get the following error
`-bash: mongodump:command not found`

I had installed `MongoDB` like this

```
echo "[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo

sudo yum -y install mongo-10gen-server mongodb-org-shell
```

What are we missing exactly?
Cheers and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using mongodump: "mongodump: command not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123771/using-mongodump-mongodump-command-not-found)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/), mongodump is part of the mongodb-org-tools package, which you haven't installed